# C#: How to iterate trough own Dictionary to write XElements in my XDocument?

Tags: c#, xml, file

I got a dictionary with different propertys. Now I want to create a XML File out of this dictionary, but I dont know how I can iterate trough each entry in my dictionary.
In my dictionary there are 2 propertys called quantity and price.

So this is actually what my code looks like.

```
XDocument xDoc = new XDocument(
            new XElement("itemlist",
                    new XElement("item",
                        new XAttribute("article", "1"),
                        new XAttribute("quantity", "150"),
                        new XAttribute("price", "20"))));

xDoc.Save("C:/Users/User/Desktop/XMLOutput.xml");
```

But I don't want to write every entry in my dictionary myself, so I'm looking for a solution something like this:

```
XDocument xDoc = new XDocument(
            new XElement("itemlist",
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, item> it in dictionary_items)
                    {                           
                        new XElement("item",
                           new XAttribute("article", it.Key),
                           new XAttribute("quantity", it.Value.quantity),
                           new XAttribute("price", it.Value.price)
                        ));
                    }

xDoc.Save("C:/Users/User/Desktop/XMLOutput.xml");
```

So I want to iterate trough each entry in my dictionary and write it as above in my XML-File. How can I do that?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Instead of the for each use a Select projection: `new XDocument(new XElement("itemlist", dictionary_items.Select(it => new XElement("item", …)).ToArray()))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.  You can use [XStreamingElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xstreamingelement?view=netframework-4.7.2) for this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp31
{
    class Program
    {
        class Item
        {
            public int quantity { get; set; }
            public double price { get; set; }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dictionary_items = new Dictionary<string, Item>();

            dictionary_items.Add("abc", new Item() { quantity = 1, price = 3.3 });
            dictionary_items.Add("def", new Item() { quantity = 1, price = 3.3 });

            XDocument xDoc = new XDocument(
                new XStreamingElement("itemlist",
                     from it in dictionary_items
                     select new XElement("item",
                               new XAttribute("article", it.Key),
                               new XAttribute("quantity", it.Value.quantity),
                               new XAttribute("price", it.Value.price)))
                );
            Console.WriteLine(xDoc.ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

outputs

```
<itemlist>
  <item article="abc" quantity="1" price="3.3" />
  <item article="def" quantity="1" price="3.3" />
</itemlist>
```

Comment: Have a little problem too, maybe you can solve this aswell: with the xDoc.Save()-Method there is automatically the <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> Tag in my XML-File...but I dont need this in my XML-File at the end. Is there a simple way, that I can avoid it to be written in my XML-File?

Comment: XDocument.ToString omits the xml declaration, so you can writ that to your file.  eg `System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fn, xDoc.ToString(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);`

Answer (score 1):

```
var list = new XElement("itemlist");
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, item> it in dictionary_items)
{                           
    list.Add(new XElement("item",
                           new XAttribute("article", it.Key),
                           new XAttribute("quantity", it.Value.quantity),
                           new XAttribute("price", it.Value.price)
                        )));
}

XDocument xDoc = new XDocument(list);
xDoc.Save("C:/Users/User/Desktop/XMLOutput.xml");
```